# Identifying the field for Lohnermäßigung/Steuerfreibetrag in the official German tax deduction spec

Tags: tax-deduction, germany, software

In Germany, you can get kind of discount on your tax if you are paying for a Kindergarten. This is called in general *[Lohnsteuerermäßigung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lohnsteuerfreibetrag)* and gives you a *Steuerfreibeitrag* (there are obviously also other types of this, not only Kindergarten).

However, I fail to identify this field in the [official PDF spec](https://www.bundesfinanzministerium.de/Content/DE/Downloads/Steuern/Steuerarten/Lohnsteuer/Programmablaufplan/2017-11-23-PAP-2018-anlage-1-geaendert.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=1) for the tax deduction implementation.

Which one could this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s `LZZFREIB`:

> Der als elektronisches Lohnsteuerabzugsmerkmal für den Arbeitgeber nach § 39e EStG festgestellte oder in der Bescheinigung für den Lohnsteuerabzug 2018 eingetragene Freibetrag für den Lohnzahlungszeitraum in Cent